# Get created directory path and used it in script

Tags: shell

Scenario goes like this,
shell script to create backup directory with current date and use it's absolute path in shell script.

## !/bin/bash

var1="/home/oracle/"`date +%Y%m%d`

*mkdir $var1*

after creating directory i need to use directorypath in oracle rman script like this.

*backup current controlfile format '**direcotrypath**'/cntrl.ctl;*

Comment: You do not need the quotes for making a directory - Also need the `$` symbol - i.e. `mkdir $var1`

Comment: thanks for point out the error ... my main concern is to use created directory  path into backup script later . . may be there is some inbuilt function to get path of created folder .

Comment: If you create a directory, you _know_ the name you have just created. If you are unsure, you can make "mkdir xx; cd xx; pwd" and it will print the absolute pathname of the dir you just created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

path=$(pwd)"/date"

echo $path

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP asks for.